# Is getBoundingClientRect().top on ios safari behaving as expected for touch scrolling?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have a div that I'm scrolling with `position:fixed`. This div is a little longer than the height of the viewport, so if the user touches it, I want them to scroll the div until it fully appears on the screen (I can't use overflow for other reasons).  The logic is fine, I've tested it on chrome tablet/desktop, but I'm using `document.getElementById("myelement").getBoundingClientRect().top` to calculate when we have left the screen.

But on iOS tablets (and presumably phones, but I don't have one to test) I'm observing a weird thing. When I touch and drag up, `getBoundingClientRect().top` grows uncontrollably negative, even though the position is fixed.  When I attach the debugger and highlight the div, I see that the blue shaded area is moving up as I drag my finger, even though the div isn't moving at all. So it seems that `top` is reporting where Safari calculates the top value, even though it's not where it's rendered.

I'm not very familiar with iOS/Safari, so maybe this is by design? If it is, how can I get a value that would match `top` reported in other browsers?

I was able to recreate this effect with this minimal code (just copy enough test2 divs to create a scrolling requirement)

```
<h2>Test</h2>

<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; z-index:10001">
    <ul>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; width:100%">
    <div style="height:50px; width:95%">test2</div>
    <div style="height:50px; width:95%">test2</div>
    <div style="height:50px; width:95%">test2</div>
    <div style="height:50px; width:95%">test2</div>


</div>
```